# Ubuntu doesn't work on my mac, what can I do?

Tags: dual-boot, macbook, system-installation, refit

i need some help with a macbook. Well, some months ago I have installed ubuntu and kali linux, on a HD external, and it works good on my macbook thanks to refit.
Today I have installed refit, in my sister's macbook, doing the same things I did in mine. I have installed refit, and I plugged my External HD on her computer. When turned  on the computer, I selected the penguin Icon,and with all my surprise It didn't work. There was written `no bootable disk` . Therefore I thought there was a problem with the partition of her computer, so on the main page of refit I selected `partition too`l I followed the instructions.

When the program finished to repair partitions, I restarted the computer, and tried again to open linux. This time there was a different written `no system disk`. I can't understand why it happens only in her computer, because in mine it works well.

Also when I start the computer, on the main page of refit, next to apple icon, there is a square icon, black and grey where there is written `boot legacy ox HD` what does it means? please I need some help. Should I erase the whole computer's hardisk, and install all things all over again??? or there is a easier way??
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The tool that you believed "repaired" the disk in fact created a [hybrid MBR.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) This is a *dangerous hack* that Apple uses to help support dual-boot configurations of OS X and Windows. Although hybrid MBRs are required in some configurations, they're overused, and playing with them without understanding them is like giving a toddler a flamethrower. I've seen far too many reports of people who've trashed their systems because of hybrid MBR weirdness. I strongly recommend that you read the page I linked to earlier so that you'll be better able to understand the risks and avoid figuratively burning your disk to the ground.

Although it's possible to boot Linux in BIOS mode on a Mac by using a hybrid MBR, IMO it's generally better to boot in EFI mode *without* using a hybrid MBR. My [Web page on this topic](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/) provides information on doing this, but it's a bit outdated and it uses a very old Mac as a reference. It's actually easier to get working with some more modern Macs, but the procedure is somewhat different, and I don't have a reference to documentation on doing it.

The icon you describe in your last paragraph is a generic icon for launching a BIOS-mode OS from rEFIt. It appears because rEFIt believes it's found an unknown bootable BIOS-mode OS on the hard disk. It might or might not have done so. Chances are it appeared because you created a hybrid MBR on the disk, and chances are that hybrid MBR is doing nothing useful.

As to your main problem, booting external disks on Macs has always been a hit-or-miss proposition, especially in BIOS mode. It's likely that your sister's Mac's firmware just doesn't work for this job. You might have better luck by upgrading from the no-longer-maintained rEFIt to my fork of it, [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) which supports booting Linux kernels (3.3.0 and later) in EFI mode. In fact, if you know what you're doing, you should be able to install rEFInd on the external disk so that it will launch on any Mac when you hold down the Option key and select the external disk when you power on the computer. To do this, you'll need to install rEFInd to the external disk's EFI System Partition (ESP) as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. (That's likely gibberish to you now. If you read the [rEFInd documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) and [my page on EFI boot loaders for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders) you should better understand how to do it.) In any event, once rEFInd is running, it *should* be able to detect and launch Linux on your external disk without using GRUB or relying on the hackish BIOS-mode tricks that you're using now to launch Linux.